# Codewars Scramblies(couldn't pass the last test-performance issue)

Tags: javascript

Please take a look at the lines of code written below. It's too slow to pass the last test(long string).
Is it a bad idea to iterate over each element in the array in this case? Is it the main cause responsible for slowing down the execution when dealing with long string?

The question to solve is described as follows:

Complete the function scramble(str1, str2) that returns true if a portion of str1 characters can be rearranged to match str2, otherwise returns false.
This is the [link](https://www.codewars.com/kata/55c04b4cc56a697bb0000048) to the question

```
function scramble(str1, str2) {
 let count=0
 let targetAry=str2.split('')
 let strAry=str1.split('')
 for (let i=0;i<targetAry.length;i++){
   for(let j=0;j<strAry.length;j++){
     if(targetAry[i]===strAry[j]){
       strAry.splice(j,1)
       count++
       break
     }
   }
 }
 return (count==targetAry.length)
}
```

**Answer from [CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance)**

```
const countStr = (str) => {
    const obj = {};
    for (const char of str) {
        obj[char] = (obj[char] || 0) + 1;
    }
    return obj;
}
const scramble = (str1, str2) => {
    const [obj1, obj2] = [str1, str2].map(countStr);
    return (  
        Object.entries(obj2).every(([key, val]) => obj1[key] >= val)
    );
};
```

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I just put the description and link above. Sorry for omitting this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is `O(n ^ 2)` - for each character in one array, and for each character in another array, you're carrying out an operation. Your `splice` is also messing up the indicies.

Reduce the computational complexity. One way to do this is by turning each string into an object with a count of characters.

```
const countStr = (str) => {
    const obj = {};
    for (const char of str) {
        obj[char] = (obj[char] || 0) + 1;
    }
    return obj;
}
const scramble = (str1, str2) => {
    const [obj1, obj2] = [str1, str2].map(countStr);
    return (
        Object.keys(obj1).length === Object.keys(obj2).length &&
        Object.entries(obj1).every(([key, val]) => obj2[key] === val)
    );
};
```

Comment: It gives `false`, which I'd think would be desired, since the letters can't be rearranged to match the other, right?

Comment: I changed your answer a bit so that the test can be passed and included it in my question section. Thanks for your explanation. I am quite new to Javascript and didn't know anything about Big O notation before you brought it up. It opens the new door to dealing with Javascript algorithm for me.